# Python multiprocessing.Pool & memory

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using `Pool.map` for a scoring procedure:

1. "cursor" with millions of arrays from a data source
2. calculation
3. save the result in a data sink

The results are independent.

I'm just wondering if I can avoid the memory demand. At first
it seems that every array goes into python and then the 2 and 3 are
proceed. Anyway I have a speed improvement.

```
#data src and sink is in mongodb#
def scoring(some_arguments):
        ### some stuff  and finally persist  ###
    collection.update({uid:_uid},{'$set':res_profile},upsert=True)


cursor = tracking.find(timeout=False)
score_proc_pool = Pool(options.cores)    
#finaly I use a wrapper so I have only the document as input for map
score_proc_pool.map(scoring_wrapper,cursor,chunksize=10000)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way with python for this purpose?

Comment: any code snippets to help us along?

Answer (score 1):

The `map` functions of a `Pool` internally convert the iterable to a list if it doesn't have a `__len__` attribute. The relevant code is in [`Pool.map_async`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04981ac65138/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l297), as that is used by `Pool.map` (and `starmap`) to produce the result - which is also a list.

If you don't want to read all data into memory first, you should use [`Pool.imap`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) or `Pool.imap_unordered`, which will produce an iterator that will yield the results as they come in.

Comment: I'm just wondering why imap and imap_ordered give me *oom kill* and map not? Is there any way to prevent this from python. I played with chunksize but without success.

Comment: Uh, that sounds serious. What you must ensure is that you can keep up with consuming the results, the process reading the results should be much faster then the processes producing them, otherwise the chunks will pile up. And a chunksize this high seems rather excessive - it means wait for the first worker to produce 10000 results, then for the secont 100000, and so on. I've written a quick example to show how chunks are processed [here](http://pastebin.com/YStmwQB3). I would use a chunksize between 10 and 100 times the cpu count...

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but it seems a challenge. I'm getting a kill or the eating memory case with swapping. Think about another approach.