# Reducing the memory size of a list for multiprocessing.Pool.starmap()

Tags: python, list, numpy, memory, multiprocessing

So I have created a list for multiprocessing stuff(in particular, it is `multiprocessing.Pool().starmap()`) and want to reduce its memory size. The list is the following:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

lst1 = np.arange(1000)
lst3 = np.arange(0.05, 4, 0.05)

lst1_1 = list(product(enumerate(lst3),
                      (item for item in product(lst1, lst1) if item[0] < item[1])
                      ))
```

Its memory size calculated from `sys.getsizeof(lst1_1)` is `317840928`

---

Seeing that the type of `lst1` is `int32`, I thought changing the dtype of the lst to `int16` can reduce the memorysize of `lst1` and, consequently,  `ls1_1` by a half since `int16` takes up half the memory as `int32` data, so I did the following:

```
lst2 = np.arange(1000, dtype = np.int16)
lst2_1 = list(product(enumerate(lst3),
                      (item for item in product(lst2, lst2) if item[0] < item[1])
                      ))
```

Surprisingly, the memory size of `lst2_1` calculated by `sys.getsizeof(lst2_1)` is still `317840928`.

---

My questions are the following:

1) Is the memory size of the list independent of the datatype of the source data?

2) If so, then what's the best way to reduce the memory size of the list without converting to a generator?

Note that the reason why converting to a generator won't help is because even if it gets converted to a generator, when it is thrown into `multiprocessing.Pool().starmap()`, it gets converted back to a list anyway.

Comment: `getsizeof` only measures the size of the buffer of the list that holds the 'pointers'.  It's roughly proportional to the len of the list.  It does not include the size of the objects in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting the arrays to Python `List`s before you check the size of these arrays.
The integers inside are converted to Python objects. When you do that, it results in a much larger size. Here is an example behavior of your code.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

lst1 = np.arange(1000)
lst2 = np.arange(1000, dtype = np.int16)

print(sys.getsizeof(lst1)) # 4096
print(sys.getsizeof(lst2)) # 2096
print(sys.getsizeof(list(lst1))) # 9112
print(sys.getsizeof(list(lst2))) # 9112
```

`Numpy` is a C based library, so you can choose which integer type to use (just like int, long, long long). You need your data to stay in C-type so that those advantages can be preserved. That's why `Numpy` has so many functions in itself, keeping the operations and the data at a lower level.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, every item in a list are by default python objects, so they take as much memory as any other python object would right? If that's true, does it mean there is no way to bump down the memory size of any python list?

Comment: That is correct. Python objects carry more information than their cognates in C, and so require more memory. Reducing the size by other means could be; change of algorithm, partitioning the list and loading it part by part (a lower level operation), or simply compressing (not preferable in frequently accessed data).

Comment: I think I will look into partitioning the list as the last resort

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671215/python-multiprocessing-pool-memory

Comment: I am actually looking into converting an `starmap` operation to an `imap` operation. I am still figuring out if it is even possible. The reason why I am using `starmap` in the first place is that the function has a lot of arguments: some are numpy arrays, some are tuples.